# Maximizing the target variable

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need help with this.

Data look like:

```
ProductX      Total_share_of_visits     Total_Cost_Tax_Included        Gross
17220.0       65.73                     272213.76                      190549.632
79570.0       362.17                    1257842.56                     880489.792
```

ProductX: number of units sold

total_sahre_of_visits: number of visits in the market (by employees) to sale the product

total_cost_tax_included: (price of one unit + cost of employees sent to the market to sale the product)*ProductX. Which mean that this is the income

Q1: Compute the gros if it is of order 70%

Answer: I computed the gross variable 'Gross' = total_cost_tax_included *70 /100

Q2: build a simple model that calculate the additional profit generated if the client increases or decrease the number of employees sent to the market by 20%

Answer: I fit a very simple linear regression model (I could computed this directly, but I'am asked to use a model).The model show mean absolute error of (3.3945175965265104e-16). And after that I want to change 'Total_share_of_visits' and 'Total_cost_tax_inluded' (because adding employees by 20% will add cost and of corse increase the number of visits to sale the product) and pass this as a test_dataset to the model to find Gross. After that I will compute total Gross before adding 20% employees and after adding and see the difference. Is it Correct?

Q3: Till now I think I'am correct. And then this question What is the optimal number of employees needed to maximize profit(Gross)?

Answer: I don't know how to use the model to find this or if there is another function in sklearn to do this. I need help here ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cummulative Accuracy Profile for deciding it.

Say you have **100000** customers and *from previous experience* you know that **only 10% of them** actually buys your product.And now we want to optimize number of employees to maximize profit.So we need to target customers more appropriately to get better response rate.

So 1st you need to *build a customer segmentation model*(binary model as either customer will buy or not so we can use **logistic regression**) to predict whether they will buy or not based on previous records.This model will **help us access the likelihood of certain type of cutomers purchasing based on their characterstics**.

eg.Say it will tell us male customers with a certain age group who browse mobile are most likely to purchase your product.

So it will **rank our customers according to the probability of purchasing a product**.Now we can plot a graph for actual number of sales:
Y axis-no. of Sales(maximum 10000 in case of my example)
X axis-no. of cutomers(100000 in case of my example)

Now we can see and **analyze from the graph say like even at 60000 at x axis we are getting 9500 sales**.So we can set our number of employees to be **60000** in place of 100000.

Comment: Thank you for your help